# How to optimize a simple name matching script?

Tags: python

I apologize if this is a really simple question, but I have a rather long python script that I have no idea how to optimize. The script takes an input and places an alterative adjective before it.
Example: If input is "Adam" program would output "Awesome Adam".

Right now I have 26 nested elif functions. I know there is a simpler way to do this.
I assume there is a way to do this by using something like nameinput[0], but have python read it as the variable *a* rather than the string "A" and then having my list of adjectives be referenced by that letter.

Thank you so much in advance!

```
a = "Awesome"
b = "Brave"
c = "Couragous"
d = "Daring"
e = "Energetic"
f = "Fun"
g = "Great"
h = "Heartfelt"
i = "Imaginative"
j = "Joyful"
k = "Kind"
l = "Lawful"
m = "Maternal"
n = "Nice"
o = "Open"
p = "Positive"
q = "Quirky"
r = "Resourceful"
s = "Smooth"
t = "Talkative"
u = "Understanding"
v = "Victorious"
w = "Wacky"
x = "Xenial"
y = "Young"
z = "Zany"
def name_casecheck(nameinput):
    if nameinput[0].isupper() == True:
        name(nameinput)
    else:
        print("Please capitalize your own name!")
        
        nameinput[0] = ()
def name(nameinput):
    if nameinput[0] == "A":
        print(a + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "B":
        print(b + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "C":
        print(c + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "D":
        print(d + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "E":
        print(e + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "F":
        print(f + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "G":
        print(g + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "H":
        print(h + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "I":
        print(i + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "J":
        print(j + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "L":
        print(k + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "M":
        print(m + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "N":
        print(n + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "O":
        print(o + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "P":
        print(p + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "Q":
        print(q + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "R":
        print(r + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "S":
        print(s + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "T":
        print(t + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "U":
        print(u + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "V":
        print(v + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "W":
        print(w + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "X":
        print(x + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "Y":
        print(y + " " + nameinput + "!")
    elif nameinput[0] == "Z":
        print(z + " " + nameinput + "!")
    else:
        print("I didn't quite understand that, try another name?")
        
        
name_casecheck("Andrew")
```

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code a lot by using a dictionary!
Dictionaries are ways to relate keys to values - think of a list with names instead of indexes.
This way, you can use the first letter of the name to access the word you want:

```py
word_to_add = {
    "a": "Awesome",
    "b": "Brave",
    "c": "Couragous",
    "d": "Daring",
    "e": "Energetic",
    "f": "Fun",
    "g": "Great",
    "h": "Heartfelt",
    "i": "Imaginative",
    "j": "Joyful",
    "k": "Kind",
    "l": "Lawful",
    "m": "Maternal",
    "n": "Nice",
    "o": "Open",
    "p": "Positive",
    "q": "Quirky",
    "r": "Resourceful",
    "s": "Smooth",
    "t": "Talkative",
    "u": "Understanding",
    "v": "Victorious",
    "w": "Wacky",
    "x": "Xenial",
    "y": "Young",
    "z": "Zany"
}

# I added a conversion to the first character so you won't have to capitalize your name (the .lower())
def name(nameinput):
    print(word_to_add[nameinput[0].lower()] + " " + nameinput + "!")


name("Andrew")
```

To shortly explain the changes:
`word_to_add` is a dictionary where the key is the first letter, and the value is the word to add (hence the name).
By getting the first letter of the word, and converting it to lowercase, we can make sure we don't run into the capitalization issue.
Then, using the first letter as a **key**, we search for the corresponding word in the dictionary, and print it out.

Comment: Wow! I am clearly still a learner  - this helps me in a lot of ways because it also opens my eyes to a new function I've never seen. Thank you so much for your kindness Adid!

Comment: For sure! I don't know how managed before knowing dictionaries.